# Show nested button above overlay

Tags: javascript, css

I have an HTML page where I need to make a deeply nested element appear above a neighboring ancestor.

Here is an example JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nLa607g5/1/

This HTML structure can’t be changed. Using CSS (preferably) or JavaScript, is there any way I can make the red button appear on top of the overlay, but the blue portion appear behind the overlay?

The following are the two main classes that deal with the overlay and button:

```css
.overlay {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  backdrop-filter: blur(2px);
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#cntrl {
  float: left;
}

.modal {
  overflow: auto;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1050;
}

.dialog {
  background: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
}

.btn {
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay"></div>
<div id="app">
  <div id="cntrl">
    <div>
      <div>
        <div class="modal">
          <div class="dialog">
            <span>should appear behind overlay</span>
            <div class="content">
              <div class="footer">
                <button class="btn">
                      Should appear on top of overlay
                    </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, without changing the HTML, this is very hard to achieve with pure CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Impossible with CSS and no HTML. JavaScript is the only option. Basically, you append the overlay to the footer and the button to the overlay -- exactly what you'd do with HTML.

```js
const overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay');
const footer = document.querySelector('.footer');
const button = document.querySelector('.btn');
footer.append(overlay);
overlay.append(button);
```

```css
.overlay {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  backdrop-filter: blur(2px);
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#cntrl {
  float: left;
}

.modal {
  overflow: auto;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1050;
}

.dialog {
  background: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
}

.btn {
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay"></div>
<div id="app">
  <div id="cntrl">
    <div>
      <div>
        <div class="modal">
          <div class="dialog">
            <span>should appear behind overlay</span>
            <div class="content">
              <div class="footer">
                <button class="btn">
                  Should appear on top of overlay
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```